# Security rules for real-time database in Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a real-time multiplayer game using Firebase real-time database, and each move of the players will be update to the database. Moreover, I'm using authentication from a third party instead of Firebase Auth. Therefore, should I leave my rule as:

```
{
 “rules”: {
 “.read”: true,
 “.write”: true
 }
}
```

Which basically no security at all, but since player's move will be updated in real-time so that's why I think they should be allowed to read and write to my real-time database, any thoughts? just want to make sure if there'll be vulnerabilities for my apps. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, so this is a bad idea. It leaves your database wide open to be written to and read from by anyone. It's not clear *why* you don't want to have security rules but reviewing the getting started guide [Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) may help you refine the question a bit so it's more clear.

Answer (score 0):

1. You cannot use security rules without Firebase Authentication (unless you store them in either realtime database or Firestore as pointed out by @Doug. However you can access realtime database's data in security rules of realtime database only and same goes for Firestore).
2. Never ever use those rules since they allow anyone to read or write anything do the database and even wipe it in seconds.

If you are using a 3rd party auth then all your connections to the database should be made through a secure environment such as a server or cloud function. You would have to implement all the realtime functionality using websockets yourself along with handling the Authentication. Do not forget to set the rules to false so direct connection to database are closed.

Generally you would use Firebase Admin SDK on a server which does not follow any security rules so you would have to make sure a user requesting a resource is authorized to get it.

Comment: #1 is not entirely true as written.  You can certinaly use rules without auth for the purpose of [data validation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security#section-validation), which applies to web and mobile clients regardless of auth.

Comment: Hi, but if I already put my DB key in .env files and add that into git.ignore, how can they access my database and mess it up like what you said? Thanks

Comment: @Codojojo thing is you would usually pass user IDs in request body or params. Users can simply pass any ID. Now you must add an `if` statement that checks if user is allowed to access data of the ID they passed else the Admin SDK will obviously load the data